# Formatting ISO time with Luxon

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, luxon

Using **Luxon JS**, I've been trying to format datetime to output in a certain format, using the native **toISO** function:

This is what I *get*:

```
"2018-08-25T09:00:40.000-04:00"
```

And this is what I *want*:

```
"2018-08-25T13:00:40.000Z"
```

I know that they are both equivalent in terms of unix time and mean the same thing except in a different format, I just want to be able to out the second string rather than the first. I looked through the Luxon docs but was unable to find any arguments/options that would give me what I need.

Comment: You need to convert the time to utc first. Try using date.toUTC().toISO() instead of date.toISO() .... date being your date object.

Comment: Why use Luxon for that at all? The built–in *Date.prototype.toISOString* method does what you want.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As other already stated in the comments, you can use 2 approaches:

- Convert Luxon DateTime to UTC using [`toUTC`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-toUTC):

  ```
  "Set" the DateTime's zone to UTC. Returns a newly-constructed DateTime.
  ```
- Use [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method of JS Date.

You can use [`toJSDate()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/class/src/datetime.js%7EDateTime.html#instance-method-toJSDate) to get the Date object from a luxon DateTime:

```
Returns a JavaScript Date equivalent to this DateTime.
```

---

Examples:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const dt = DateTime.now();
console.log(dt.toISO())
console.log(dt.toUTC().toISO())
console.log(dt.toJSDate().toISOString())
console.log(new Date().toISOString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.26.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

From documentation I saw that in the method `.fromISO` of `DateTime` you can add an option object after the string of ISO date ("2018-08-25T09:00:40.000-04:00" in your example). In this object specify `zone: utc` like that:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

const stringDate = "2018-08-25T09:00:40.000-04:00";

const dt = DateTime.fromISO(stringDate, {zone: 'utc'});

console.log('This is your date format', dt.toISO())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/1.26.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```